# How to return elements React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I ask for your help. I have a working code and two buttons. One deletes the first element of the array, the second - the last element. How to use the "Restore" button to restore (restore) all items.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    let [array, changedArray] = useState([
{
id: 1,
title:'title 1',
price:1
},
{
id: 2,
title: 'title 2',
price: 2
},
{
id:3,
title: 'title 3',
price: 3
}
)]

 function removeFirstElement () {
 let newArray = [...array];
 newArray.shift();
 changedArray(newArray);
}

function removeLastElement() {
let newArray = [...array];
newArray.pop();
changedArray(newArray)
}

return(
<div>
<ul>{array.map(el =><li>{el.title} {el.price}</li>)}</ul>
<button onClick={removeFirstElement}>Delete first element</button>
<button onClick={removeLastElement}>Delete last element</button>
<button>Restore</button>
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could possibly do is store the initial array in a ref. When you click on the restore button you can then set your state with that ref.

```
let [array, changedArray] = useState([...])
let initialValue = useRef(array);

const onRestore = () => {
    changedArray(initialValue.current);
};

<button onClick={onRestore}>Restore</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onClick event on the reset button and call the fuction that will reload the page. That will do the job.

```
 const restoreHandler = () => {
   location.reload()
} 

<button onClick={restoreHandler}>Restore</button>
```